# belongs_to has_many association in seed.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm trying to use a *seed.rb* file with the following relations, but the problem is when I execute rails c and try to figure out which are the documentos from Meioambiente, nothing is displayed. (I`m sending a screenshot to show the behavior)

What I`m missing?

[image: Screenshot]

**seeds.rb**

```
Meioambiente.destroy_all
Documento.destroy_all
Arquivo.destroy_all
meioambiente = Meioambiente.create!([nome: 'Instituicao da COMDEC', desc: 'Criar ou apresentar Lei que institui a COMDEC. Tambem deve ser apresentado a nomeacao do coordenador da mesma, em carater de exclusividade. Tambem deve ser apresentado o Decreto que destina uma sala e um automovel para uso exclusivo da COMDEC.', prazo: Time.local(Time.now.year, 1,1)])
documento1 = Documento.create!([nome: 'Lei de Criacao da COMDEC', score: '0', meioambiente: meioambiente])
```

**Documento.rb**

```
class Documento < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :nome
  has_many :arquivos
  belongs_to :meioambiente
end
```

**meioambiente.rb**

```
class Meioambiente < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :nome, :desc, :prazo
  has_many :documentos
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "arquivos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "nome"
    t.integer  "score"
    t.boolean  "cancelado"
    t.text     "observacao"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.integer  "documento_id"
  end

  add_index "arquivos", ["documento_id"], name: "index_arquivos_on_documento_id"

  create_table "documentos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "nome"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.integer  "score"
    t.integer  "meioambiente_id"
  end

  add_index "documentos", ["meioambiente_id"], name: "index_documentos_on_meioambiente_id"

  create_table "meioambiente", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "nome"
    t.text     "desc"
    t.datetime "prazo"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Comment: Why are you passing in an array as the argument to `create!`? It should be a hash.

Answer (score 0):

As --ptd said, I was passing an array, instead of hash. Solved. Thanks.